# How to horizontally draw a line passing through a point A until it reaches the border of a node B using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given point A and a node B with an ellipse shape, how to draw a line from A horizontally until it reaches the border of B?

[image: tikz]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 10):

One way is to use the intersection library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=center:$B$] (B) at (2,1);

    \draw[name path=B node] (B) ellipse (0.5 and 1.2);
    \path [name path=A--B] (A) -| (B);
    \path [name intersections={of=A--B and B node}];
    \fill (A) circle (2pt);
    \draw (A)  -- (intersection-1);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your example, I see no line drawing from A to B.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the example and now I have also compiled it... I see a line now.

Comment: That's not horizontal line. I think for what you are doing draw from a point to a node shape automatically stops at the border. But I will take a look at the `intersections` lib.

Comment: Yes, I think the take home message is the intersections library. I hope that I have corrected my example now.

Comment: Yes indeed this time it works.

Comment: Better late than never.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `intersections` library available, I agree that it's the best way to go for this. But versions of TikZ prior to the introduction of `intersections` (which are apparently fairly common in the wild) didn't have the capability to automatically compute the intersection point between a line and an elliptical node. If it were a circular node, you could do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
 \node[draw,circle,minimum height=3cm] (B) at (2,1) {B};
 \draw (A) -- (intersection cs: first line={(A)--+(10,0)},second node=B,solution=2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but that doesn't work for ellipses. So here are some alternatives.

One option would be to "cheat" by drawing the line before the node, and then filling the node with an opaque color:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
 \node[ellipse,minimum height=3cm] (B) at (2,1) {};
 \draw (A) -- (intersection cs: first line={(A)--+(10,0)},second line={(B.center)--(B.south)});
 \node[fill=white,draw,ellipse,minimum height=3cm] at (B) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this is highly undesirable because it requires you to specify the same node twice.

A slightly better (but still not ideal) option is to use TikZ to manually calculate the proper position for the line to end.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
 \node[draw,ellipse,minimum height=3cm] (B) at (2,1) {B};
 \newdimen\semimajor
 \newdimen\semiminor
 \newdimen\ydiff
 \pgfextracty{\semimajor}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{B}{south}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}}
 \pgfextractx{\semiminor}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{B}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}}
 \pgfextracty{\ydiff}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}}
 \pgfmathparse{\semiminor * sqrt(1 - pow(\ydiff / \semimajor,2))};
 \draw (B.center) ++(-\pgfmathresult pt,-\ydiff) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I think `intersections` is the way to go.

Comment: I'd agree, if you have access to it. (I don't)

Comment: By the way, an explanation from whoever case the downvote would be much appreciated.

Comment: The TikZ intersections library can be used to find intersection points between a line and an elliptical node: 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (X)[draw,shape=ellipse,minimum height=3cm,name path=X] at (0,0) {x};
  \draw[name path=L] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
  \path[name intersections={of=X and L}];
  \fill[red]  (intersection-1) circle (2pt);
  \fill[blue] (intersection-2) circle (2pt);

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Comment: @Martin: I saw your answer. Why did you repost the code sample in a comment?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: The code in my comment was to show that TikZ can can automatically calculate intersections between an elliptical node and a line. You write "TikZ itself doesn't have the capability to automatically compute the intersection point between a line and an elliptical node". I just commented on that.

Comment: @Martin: On my computer (on which I have TeXLive 2009), my comment is accurate: TikZ itself is not able to compute the intersection between a line and an elliptical node. I tried compiling the code in your answer before posting my own, but LaTeX complains that the `intersections` library cannot be found. Maybe I should have asked earlier, but where does this library come from?

Comment: @David: The TikZ version in TeXLive 2009 is very old. I am using the CVS version of TikZ. The intersections library is part of TikZ and is documented in the pgfmanual (see p. 130 in <http://media.texample.net/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2010-07-25.pdf>). It's easy to get the latest CVS version from <http://www.texample.net/tikz/>.

Comment: @Martin: okay, that explains it. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late, but I stumbled upon this, and the intersections machinery is overkill.  You can just specify the anchor you want the line to go to, like so:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [label=south:$A$] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \filldraw (A) circle (1pt) ;
    \node [draw, ellipse, minimum height = 2cm] (B) at (2,0) {B};

    \draw [red] (A.center) -- (B.east) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following image:

[image: Line from A to the opposite side of B.]

If you want the line to go to the left side, replace `(B.east)` with `(B.west)`.  If you want it to go elsewhere, you can use the anchor `(B.θ)`, where *`θ`* is an integer between 0 and 360; `0` corresponds to `east`, and adding one moves the anchor around the node boundary by one degree.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that then it might be difficult to obtain a line that is really horizontal, let's say if the node A was a little lower.

Comment: Hmm, yes, didn't think of that.  It depends on whether or not your goal is "line to here" or "precisely horizontal line".  This works for the former, but you do need intersections for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Martin Heller's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/how-to-horizontally-draw-a-line-passing-through-a-point-a-until-it-reaches-the-b#comment2158_1571), we obtain an actual solution to the original question, i.e., a horizontal line segment between a point (i.e., a small circle; any node would do, including a coordinate) and an ellipse node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (B) [draw,shape=ellipse,minimum height=11ex,name path=B] {B};
  \node[circle,inner sep=.2ex,outer sep=0pt,fill] (A) at ($(B.west)-(2em,3ex)$) {};
  \node[anchor=east,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (A.west) {A};
  \path[name path=L] (A) -- (A-|B);
  \path[name intersections={of=B and L, by=int}];
  \draw[-] (A) -- (int);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: are you sure that your answer can do something that the top voted answer doesn't...? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1556/250119

Comment: @user202729 The answer you mentioned doesn't have a `\node` command as of now. That's what I was missing, so I wrote an answer of my own.